# Mutating a button into a form within a tabel cell

Tags: jquery, django

I currently have a table cell which contains a form and allows me to update a row in the database.

However I hope to be able to use Jquery to make the UI cleaner and user friendly.

http://i48.tinypic.com/mvq80n.png

what I visualize the end result to be after an onclick event.

http://www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/attachment.php?attach_id=f174a5e079756755f4c947eb8960b556&mid=id.380435762042825&hash=AQAYxjuwritoKoQZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) might be of use to use. It allows on click (or other events) to make text editable. [Here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html) you can find some demos.

Comment: can u go a little into the specifics?

Comment: Look at the source code if the demo. That should be helpful. Also the documentation provides examples....